# ARTool package in R - multiple within factors

Tags: r, statistics

I have recently discovered the ARTool package for R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ARTool/) when looking for a non-parametric alternative for a repeated measures ANOVA.

I have used ARTool and find it really very useful, but I came across a problem, that I am not sure how to deal with. Specifically, the Df.res seem to be strongly inflated as soon as I have more than one within  factor.  I have not come across this when I tried it with two between factors, a between and a within factor, or two between and one within factor, but whenever I add a second within factor, Df.res seems to become inflated.

I just wondered whether I am misunderstanding something or maybe there is an explanation that I am not aware of.

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!